# AOC G2460V monitor output does not work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, monitor

I have a tiny problem with my monitor. I'm using ubuntu 16.10, and after I upgraded to this new version of ubuntu, my sound stopped working. I plugged my earbuds into the monitor, it still didn't work. I checked alsamixer to see if any of the sounds are muted/disabled, but none of them were... I really need help ASAP.

If I plug my earbud directly to my pc, it works.

Comment: Only HDMI or DP connections support audio. Assuming you're using one of those, have you already checked which output is selected? If it works with the internal sound card ("directly to my PC") then that's the currently selected output.

Comment: I have selected the correct output. I just realised that I have "mode" option missing in my sound settings. I guess it's either my monitor speaker isn't configured properly, or the system itself doesn't detect my speaker well? if that's the case, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: It's weird indeed. I would try toggling to the internal card and back again to HDMI/DP.

Comment: What do you mean by toggling to the internal card?

Comment: I checked my pulseaudio volume control, and it saids i have the HDMI and DisplayPort plugged in. When I play a song through that, it shows me that it works, but I can't hear anything with my earbuds or with my built-in speaker

Comment: I mean change the output to the internal then back again to HDMI/DP.  But you probably did that already. If so, I'm out of suggestions and I don't have any 16.10 installed to test it. I don't know what changed from the previous release either.

Comment: I tried reinstalling all the soundcard drivers... It worked perfectly when I was at ubuntu 16.04. But I don't really think the tiny update would have changed the entire sound system...

Comment: I agree and that's why I'm out of ideas, except suggesting to test it in a 16.10 live session. If it works there then chances are it'll work if installed from scratch instead of an 16.04 >16.10 online update. But fully updating your currently installed system may also work.

Comment: I actually do have a tiny guess. Since the new update ubuntu 16.10 has a new kernel version, I think that's why the sound isn't working. The DisplayPort module is outdated. I'm not sure though, but if it is, how do I fix it?

Comment: I am still looking for an answer